# How to handle sparse array that grows arbitrarily

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I'm looking for a ( C++ ) data structure to store information about points on a 2D grid. There will be some initial values populated for a section of the grid, then new points will be set in a non-deterministic fashion, one at a time. The tricky part is, the new points are not always being added on the same 'side' of the array. The grid needs to be able to grow in any direction (up/left/down/right).

There's also the possibility that points will be added multiple spots past the current extent of the array. In this sense, a sparse array seems somewhat applicable, though the data is not particularly sparse, and gaps are expected to be filled eventually. In addition, sparse arrays still don't solve my "cant add things to the back of the array" problem.

One possible solution that occurred to me would be to use a hash map, with keys representing the coordinates.

```
std::map<std::vector<int>, MyStructClass> gridMap;
gridMap[{1,2}] = myStructInstance1;
gridMap[{-2,4}] = myStructInstance2;
//...etc
MyStructClass whatsAtSomePosition = gridMap[{3,1}];
```

I'm not convinced this would be the most efficient data structure, but I have not been able to find something else that fits my needs. What other options do I have in C++?

Comment: Isn't a `map`/`unordered_map` a basic sparse array implementation?

Comment: If gaps are expected to be filled eventually, then is there a reasonable or known size which will not be exceeded?

Comment: @Bernard, you're right, I can probably assume it wont grow more than 100 or so in any direction. And yes, an `unordered_map` seems like a simple way to represent a sparse array, especially considering I have no need to perform any matrix-esque operations on it.

Comment: If it's only 100 or so and you want fast performance, I'd rather not use a sparse array.  I'll probably write a wrapper over a `std::deque` so that I can use negative indices, and grow the `deque` on either side if I need to store something at an index that does not exist yet.  Having 40000 of `MyStructClass` won't be anything close to 1MB unless `MyStructClass` contains a large static array.

Comment: This sounds like a situation where two linked lists does the trick.